# IOS Array Testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, html

Here is my current code:

```
int i = 1;


NSString * StockOneYahooFinance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=S+Historical+Prices"];
NSString * PulledStockOne = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:StockOneYahooFinance] encoding:1 error:nil];

for (i=1;i=30;i++){

NSString *StartPulling = [[PulledStockOne componentsSeparatedByString:@"nowrap align="] objectAtIndex:i];

NSString *StartOpen = [[StartPulling componentsSeparatedByString:@">"] objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *Open = [[StartOpen componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"] objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *StartClose = [[StartPulling componentsSeparatedByString:@">"] objectAtIndex:9];
NSString *Close = [[StartClose componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"] objectAtIndex:0];

    year.text = Close;

i++;
}
```

But to the point I click the only button on the screen and it does exactly what I want it pulls the stocks open and close price for the day. But my current issue is I want it to pull all of these as an array so how can I do this?

Comment: Is `i=30;` correct for what you have in your for-loop's middle expression? This will be an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing:

```
for (i=1;i=30;i++){
```

it should be:

```
for (i=1;i<=30;i++){
```

Second one, do not increment 'int i' value on the end of loop because 'for' loop already do this. For quick'n dirty way of debugging add:

```
NSLog(@"Current iteration: %i", i);
```

as the first function in 'for' loop to see what's happening there.

Comment: Thank you very much that has fixed sevral other questions that I was going bring up at a latter point...

Comment: But im not sure if that answers my orgianl question?